# How do I loop this Python PIL code to repeat with different images?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the following code that uses PIL to paste an image on top on another.
I want to repeat this process to do it automatically with 1000+ images. Is there a way to loop it by choosing 1000+ images from a folder and pasting them on top of another 1000+ images from another folder?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

img = Image.open('image1.png', 'r')
img_w, img_h = img.size
background = Image.open('image2.png', 'r')
bg_w, bg_h = background.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 1, (bg_h - img_h) // 6)
background.paste(img, offset)

background.save('out.png')
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done. No, we will not write code for you, nor design it. You need to think about the *intended logic* first - *how* do you want to choose the images? Do you want a specific number of images, or "all of them", or just what? What is the *rule that tells you* which image should be pasted on top of what other image? You mention two folders - are they supposed to correspond to each other in some way? What should happen if your expectations about the folder contents are not met?

Comment: After that, you need to [try to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and if you're still stuck, ask a *specific* question relating to your attempt. For example, if you're stuck because you don't know how to find all the images in a folder, then you should research that, look for previous Stack Overflow answers, and if all else fails ask a specific question (that one in particular, I can guarantee you can figure out with a search engine).

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that you want all images in one folder to go over all images in another folder.

You need to itr over all the file in your directories and except `IOError` in case that there isn't it supported image file you've itr'd over.

You will need to import `os`, and filename the image is saved as is the iteration number.

This is what your code would look like:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os

dir = "C:/Users/User/Pictures/"
dir2 = "C:/Users/User/Pictures/"

images = os.listdir(dir)
images2 = os.listdir(dir2)
itr = 1

for image in images:
    for image2 in images2:
        try:
            img = Image.open(dir + image, 'r')
            img_w, img_h = img.size
            background = Image.open(dir + image2, 'r')
            print("Image = " + image + " background = " + image2 + " at itr "+ str(itr))
            print("")
            bg_w, bg_h = background.size
            offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 1, (bg_h - img_h) // 6)
            background.paste(img, offset)
            background.save('./How do I loop this Python PIL code/' + str(itr)+ ".png")
            itr += 1
        except IOError:
            pass
```